# time data with irregular intervals in HighChart

Tags: highcharts

I have a time data with irregular intervals like the following :

```
data: [
            [Date.UTC(1970,  10, 27), 12   ],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 29), 8 ]
]
```

in [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time) example the time different is shown as complete to the flow, what i really want is to have the difference as zero, So the data between 27 and 29 will be filed with 0 and the Date will be 28, i did it manually but i wonder if there is something available in highchart to do something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible yet. See the links below -

[Discussion on forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=12487&p=55565&hilit=datetime+missing+with+0#p55565)

[Request on user voice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2280551-allow-line-charts-to-handle-missing-data-without-i?ref=title)

Doing it manually is the only way to go and that you have done already.

I had the similar problem, in my case I took care of it on the server-side. I am using Java so used HashMap with date as the key.